# Aggregating and plotting Data in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, data-science

Suppose I have a Dataframe

```
Product |   Price
------------------
    A   |   20
    B   |   10
    A   |   10
    B   |   15
    A   |
```

How should I get the aggregated average values (excluding null values) and plot a graph.

```
A   | 15
B   | 12.5
```

So I would plot a graph for this table. I have though of using groupby but not sure how it would work for this scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use groupby and create a barplot after that:

```
import seaborn as sns

p_df = df.groupby('Product', as_index=False)['Price'].agg({'Avg':np.mean})

#barplot with seaborn
sns.barplot(p_df.Product, p_df.Avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do groupby in the dataframe by

```
#lets suppose your dataframe is df
df.groupby('product').mean()
```

this will return you a new data frame